# Past continuous or present perfect continuous?

Tags: tense

If you see two people talking and then they stop. One of them comes up to you and you ask:

1 What were you (just) talking about?

or

2 What have you been talking about?

Comment: I would say the first was more idiomatic in those circumstances.

Comment: Do you find 2 wrong or nor idiomatic?

Comment: 2 is more likely to be used about a particular conversation with someone, not necessarily an immediate conversation, and it often has a critical tone, as in: I saw you with Jane in the pub. What have you been talking about with her?**

Comment: But how can "I saw" line up with "What have you been talking with her"? It's like when I saw you in the pub you have been talking.... do they match?

Comment: @Kate Bunting could you explain why?

Comment: @anouk Because we use _were talking_ of a conversation that has just finished. "What have you been talking about?" sounds, as Ronald says, like a slightly suspicious question about a recent, but not necessarily immediate, conversation.

Comment: @Kate Bunting How about "what have you talked about?"

Comment: @anouk The only context in which that would be idiomatic is something like this: "I've been enjoying some long conversations with X." - "What [sort of thing] have you talked about?"

Comment: @Kate Bunting "what sort of thing have you talked about" , do you mean what topics have you talked about, different topics?

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant.

Comment: @Kate Bunting By "sort of thing" you mean more than one topic?

Comment: If I had to ask someone what sort of thing their recent conversations had been about, I wouldn't know whether they had discussed one topic or several!

Comment: @ Kate Bunting What I mean is "what sort of thing have you talked about" could mean several topics, not just one?